# How to create a new table that takes the average of columns in other tables based on name

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Average_Professor

SELECT ie.Instructor
      ,SUM(ie.instreffective_avg + h.howmuchlearned_avg + ir.instrrespect_avg +
 iv.instroverall_avg + av.availability_avg)/5
FROM   instreffective_average ie
JOIN   howmuchlearned_average h  USING (Instructor)
JOIN   instrrespect_average   ir USING (Instructor)
JOIN   instructoroverall_average   iv USING (Instructor)
JOIN   availability_average   av USING (Instructor)
GROUP  BY Instructor
```

It's giving me error code 1166.  If I omit "CREATE TABLE Professor_average"  then the script runs, yet I don't have the table created.

Answer (score 1):

Try naming the calculation column:

```
CREATE TABLE Average_Professor
SELECT ie.Instructor
      ,SUM(ie.instreffective_avg + h.howmuchlearned_avg + ir.instrrespect_avg +
 iv.instroverall_avg + av.availability_avg)/5 as calculation_value
FROM   instreffective_average ie
JOIN   howmuchlearned_average h  USING (Instructor)
JOIN   instrrespect_average   ir USING (Instructor)
JOIN   instructoroverall_average   iv USING (Instructor)
JOIN   availability_average   av USING (Instructor)
GROUP  BY Instructor
```

Comment: Yes that will create a new column called calculation_value, but I want all this information created as a new table.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the create table statement. Updated the answer.